# Pandas: Creating a histogram from string counts

Tags: pandas

I need to create a histogram from a dataframe column that contains the values "Low', 'Medium', or 'High'. When I try to do the usual df.column.hist(), i get the following error.

```
ex3.Severity.value_counts()
Out[85]: 
Low       230
Medium     21
High       16
dtype: int64

ex3.Severity.hist()


TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-86-7c7023aec2e2> in <module>()
----> 1 ex3.Severity.hist()

C:\Users\C06025A\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\plotting.py in hist_series(self, by, ax, grid, xlabelsize, xrot, ylabelsize, yrot, figsize, bins, **kwds)
2570         values = self.dropna().values
2571 
->2572         ax.hist(values, bins=bins, **kwds)
2573         ax.grid(grid)
2574         axes = np.array([ax])

C:\Users\C06025A\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py in hist(self, x, bins, range, normed, weights, cumulative, bottom, histtype, align, orientation, rwidth, log, color, label, stacked, **kwargs)
5620             for xi in x:
5621                 if len(xi) > 0:
->5622                     xmin = min(xmin, xi.min())
5623                     xmax = max(xmax, xi.max())
5624             bin_range = (xmin, xmax)

TypeError: unorderable types: str() < float()
```

Comment: My guess here is because your data is just strings are you wanting `ex3.Severity.value_counts().hist()`?

Comment: thanks, you're correct. I was assuming that his functionality was built-in for strings, and that I would not have to call value_counts

Comment: Should I post as an answer?

Answer (score 63):

```
ex3.Severity.value_counts().plot(kind='bar')
```

Is what you actually want.

When you do:

```
ex3.Severity.value_counts().hist()
```

it gets the axes the wrong way round i.e. it tries to partition your y axis (counts) into bins, and then plots the number of string labels in each bin.

Comment: Yes you are right. Strange how this works fine on Pandas with a column of numbers but with a column of text needs something completely different.

Comment: Works for me in pandas v0.19.2

Answer (score 11):

Just an updated answer (as this comes up a lot.)  Pandas has a nice module for styling dataframes in many ways, such as the case mentioned above....

`ex3.Severity.value_counts().to_frame().style.bar()`

...will print the dataframe with bars built-in (as sparklines, using excel-terminology).  Nice for quick analysis on jupyter notebooks.

see [pandas styling docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html#Bar-charts)

Answer (score 8):

It is a matplotlib issue which cannot order string together, however you can achieve the desired result by labeling the x-ticks:

```
# emulate your ex3.Severity.value_counts()
data = {'Low': 2, 'Medium': 4, 'High': 5}
df = pd.Series(data)

plt.bar(range(len(df)), df.values, align='center')
plt.xticks(range(len(df)), df.index.values, size='small')
plt.show()
```

[image: histogram]

Answer (score 5):

You assumed that because your data was composed of strings that calling `plot()` on this would automatically perform the `value_counts()` but this is not the case hence the error, all you needed to do was:

```
ex3.Severity.value_counts().hist()
```